# LaTeX resume, in classic style, templated to avoid publishing my private info

Tags: tex

I began creating and refining my resume in LaTeX a long time ago. I recently modified it such that I would feel comfortable putting it out there for others to use as a template, if they wish.

It has the unfortunate quality that when I begin modifying it, I have to tweak the white-space quite a lot if I wish to keep it at one page. I have recently given up on that goal, but I'm not sure I like the header effect when it goes over two pages.

Here's the main resume document:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\input{constants}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=.5in,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\mystreetaddress\\\mycitystatezip\\}
\chead{\Huge \textbf{Aaron Hall, MBA}}
\rhead{\myemail\\\myphonenumber\\}
\fancyfoot{}
%\headsep = 5mm
\headsep = 8mm
\usepackage{parskip} %should remove indenting
\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\date{08/22/11}
%\newenvironment{blockindentone}{\quote\YOURCOMMANDSHERE}{\endquote}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
            linkcolor=darkblue,urlcolor=darkblue,
            anchorcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue}

\newcommand{\sbullet}{\,\begin{picture}(1,1)(0,-3)\circle*{3}\end{picture}\ }


\begin{document}
\textsc{Relevant Domain Knowledge \& Experience}
\vspace{.5mm}
  \hline
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm} \textbf{Conference \& Meetup Talks}

\vspace{-2mm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5mm}
  \item Learning Python with Best Practices \sbullet Python Best Practices \sbullet Functional Programming with Python
  \item Python by Aaron Hall - a nuts and bolts overview of Python to programmers of other languages
  \item Conference talks - Linear Models with Python \sbullet The Python Datamodel: When and how to write objects 
        \sbullet Best Practices for Writing Reusable Python
  \item Consulted on Python Data Science Curriculum and instructed Python classes at CUNY and Columbia
  \item Organized and Tutored Python Office Hours Sundays for a solid year from 2014 to 2015 - still organize.

}
\end{itemize}

}}

\vspace{-1mm}
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm} \textbf{Programming Languages}

\vspace{-2mm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5mm}
  \item Primary experience: Python, JSON, OODB, YAML, BASH, HTML, RST, Orgmode, \& other Markdowns
  \item Some experience with R, SAS, SPSS, Stata, and modified Prolog
  \item Toyed with: C, Ruby, Rails, Haskell, Lisp, Fortran, COBOL, Javascript, \& \LaTeX  

}
\end{itemize}

}}

\vspace{-1mm}
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm} \textbf{Investment, Financial Products, and Accounting Knowledge}

\vspace{-2mm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5mm}
  \item Securities Licensed on Packaged Products, Stocks & Bonds, Options, and Investment Advisor Regulations
  \item Passed State of Florida Insurance and Real Estate Licensure Courses and Tests
  \item Answered over 150 Accounting and Tax Questions on Investments Pro-bono for All-Experts.com

}
\end{itemize}

}}

\vspace{-1mm}
\textsc{Professional Experience}
\vspace{.5mm}
  \hline
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm} \textbf{\anonemployer} \emph{Software Engineer \& Architect} % had as PLT \sbullet NWFSC \sbullet PCC \sbullet PSC
\sbullet New York City, NY \hfill{} October 2012 - Present

\vspace{-2mm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5mm}
  \item Developed Portal for Delivering Documentation, Information, Statistics, and Reports
  \item Led Team to use Core Technology, Idiomatic Python, Maintainable Style, Proper Unittesting, and Proper SDLC
  \item Wrote Documentation and Training on Access Control, Proprietary OODB, Python, IDE, Sphinx, and Batch Jobs
  \item Developed Tool to Document Filesets, Provide Actionable Statistics, Push to Environments, and Raise Review Requests
  \item Reviewed Projects for Best Practices \& Edited Scripts for Performance, Maintainability, and Readability
  \item Instructed Developers in Best Practices with Weekly Webinars and Regular Code Review
  \item Developed GUI for 2nd generation Release Management Tool with Pretty Urls
  \item Developed Extension to Python Logging API
  \item Developed Library to Export Data from native Python to Tableau

}
\end{itemize}

}}

\vspace{-1mm} % need after each section
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm} \textbf{Simplify IT} \emph{Computer Technician} 
\sbullet New York, NY \hfill{} March, 2012 - May, 2012

\vspace{-2mm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5mm}
  \item Troubleshot Computers and Networks, Audited and Installed Software
  \item Uploaded and Managed Inventory in an Amazon Web Store, Working With CSV and Flat Files

}
\end{itemize}

}}

\vspace{-1mm}
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm} \textbf{Thornhill Community Supportive Services Inc.} \emph{Assistant Director} 
\sbullet New York, NY \hfill{} August, 2011 - February, 2012

\vspace{-2mm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5mm}
  \item Operation Planning, Risk Management, and Network, Computer, Accounting, and Electronic Document Administration
  \item Led Team of 17 in Providing Computer Literacy and Coat, Toy, Book, and Media Community Distribution Programs

}
\end{itemize}

}}

\vspace{-1mm}
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm} \textbf{Pvt. Invest. Advisor/Sol Strategies} \emph{Investment/Strategic Planning} 
\sbullet New York, NY \hfill{} April, 2007 - October, 2012

\vspace{-2mm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5mm}
  \item Advised Sol Strategies on Firm Strategy, Business Development, Cash-Flow Management, and Billing Policy
  \item Consulted on Strategy and Wrote Financial, Investment, and Business Plans and Grant Applications

}
\end{itemize}

}}

\vspace{-1mm}
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm} \textbf{Florida State University} \emph{Research Assistant} 
\sbullet Tallahassee, FL \hfill{} August, 2007 - April, 2008

\vspace{-2mm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5mm}
  \item Teaching Fellow, Graded for Mergers and Acquisitions, Assisted in Data Collection, Research, and Proctoring Exams
  \item Programmed in SAS, Stata, SPSS, and R and Performed Regressions on Econometric Data

}
\end{itemize}

}}

\vspace{-1mm}
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm} \textbf{Merrill Lynch} \emph{Financial Advisor} 
\sbullet Pensacola, FL \hfill{} May, 2006 - April, 2007

\vspace{-2mm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5mm}
  \item Hosted Speakers, Brought in \$3 Million in Accounts, and Serviced More Than 100 House Accounts
  \item Executed Trades and Limit Orders on Exchange Traded Funds, Stocks, Options, and Auction Rate Securities

}
\end{itemize}

}}

\vspace{-1mm}
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm} \textbf{Ameriprise Financial Services} \emph{Financial Advisor} 
\sbullet New York, NY \hfill{} January, 2004 - August, 2005

\vspace{-2mm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5mm}
  \item Gave Seminars, Sold Financial Plans, Met Sales Goals, and Applied Monte Carlo Simulation \& Modern Portfolio Theory
  \item Series 7 Securities, Series 66 Investment Advisor, Life Insurance, Health Insurance, and Variable Annuity Licensed

}
\end{itemize}

}}

\vspace{-1mm}
\textsc{Education}
\vspace{.5mm}
\hline
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\textbf{University Of West Florida}, College of Business \sbullet Pensacola, FL \hfill August 2010

\vspace{-2mm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\emph{Master of Business Administration}

    \vspace{-2mm} %{\addtolength{\leftskip}{5mm}

\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5mm}
    \item 730 GMAT, 3.6 GPA, 486 Item Bibliographic Database, and International Business Strategy Championship winner
    \item Notable Papers: Predictors of Stock Market Values (Time Series) and Marketing Financial Services (Best in Class)
    \item Statistics Courses: Econometrics \sbullet Applied Regression \sbullet Probability and Statistics \sbullet Special Topics \sbullet Quantitative Methods
    \item Finance: Financial Management \sbullet Accounting Aspects \sbullet Advanced Managerial Economics \sbullet Static Optimization

}
\end{itemize}

}}
\vspace{-1mm}{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\textbf{Florida State University} \sbullet Tallahassee, FL \hfill April 2002

\vspace{-2mm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\emph{Bachelor of Science, Political Science \& Real Estate}

    \vspace{-2mm} %{\addtolength{\leftskip}{5mm}
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}\setlength{\parskip}{0cm} {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5mm}
    \item National Merit Scholar, Dean’s List, and Graduated with 169 credit hours, 3.4 GPA, Served on Boards, Volunteered
    \item Real Estate Courses: Real Estate \sbullet Real Estate Finance \sbullet Appraisal I & II \sbullet Feasibility \sbullet Legal Environment 
    \item Relevant: Game Theory \sbullet Financial Accounting \sbullet Managerial Accounting \sbullet Corporate Finance \sbullet Calculus \sbullet International Relations \sbullet Macroeconomics \sbullet Microeconomics \sbullet Comparative Government \sbullet Quantitative Methods \sbullet Research Methods

}
\end{itemize}

}}


\vspace{-1mm}
\textsc{Interests, \& Miscellany}
\vspace{.5mm}
\hline

Big Data, Databases (Hadoop, MongoDB, etc), Attended Strata 2011, Statistics, Finance, Economics, Machine Learning\\
Extensive Bibliographies: User Experience, Software Design, Finance Classics, Knowledge, and Management



\end{document}
```

and the `constants.tex` file looks like this:

```latex
\newcommand\mystreetaddress{80 foo ave., Apt N}
\newcommand\mycitystatezip{foo, BR  12345}
\newcommand\myphonenumber{+001 (555) 867 5309}
\newcommand\myemail{\url{foobar@baz.com}}

\newcommand\anonemployer{Brilliant Employer, Foo Bar Baz}
```

I have put the document on [GitHub](https://github.com/aaronchall/resume/blob/master/AaronResume.tex) so that others can leverage my efforts. Compiled, it should look like [this](https://www.scribd.com/document/335242376/Aaron-s-Resume-2016).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several weak points in this code. The main one is repeating setup and using explicit spacing in many places.

Such code should be hidden in macros as much as possible. Here are some other points.

- the `ucs` package is not recommended
- `utf8x` should better be `utf8`
- `\usepackage{fontenc}` does nothing at all
- `\headsep=8mm` is wrong syntax, better placed in the options to `geometry`
- first load packages, then do setup
- no trailing `\\` in headers
- better using the “new syntax” for fancyhdr
- use `\fancyhf{}` for clearing all fields
- no `dvips` option to `hyperref` (or `color`)
- one option per line is better for seeing what are active and for turning them on and off
- keep together things pertaining to the same package (`\headrulewidth`)

Main points: define abstract structures, that provide uniformity.

I used `\section` (hidden in `\cvsection`) and `\subsection` (hidden in `\cvsubsection`) so you can decide the format once and for all similar parts of the document. The `titlesec` package helps very much.

Some trickery is needed to keep `hyperref` quiet, in particular making `\sbullet` robust against being in a section title.

With `enumitem` you can avoid all repeated settings for each `itemize` environment.

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{constants.tex}
\newcommand\mystreetaddress{80 foo ave., Apt N}
\newcommand\mycitystatezip{foo, BR  12345}
\newcommand\myphonenumber{+001 (555) 867 5309}
\newcommand\myemail{\url{foobar@baz.com}}

\newcommand\anonemployer{Brilliant Employer, Foo Bar Baz}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[
  margin=.5in,
  includehead,
  headsep=8mm,
  headheight=30pt,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% hyperref
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  breaklinks,
  linkcolor=darkblue,
  urlcolor=darkblue,
  anchorcolor=darkblue,
  citecolor=darkblue,
}

% headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\mystreetaddress\\\mycitystatezip}
\fancyhead[C]{\Huge \textbf{Aaron Hall, MBA}}
\fancyhead[R]{\myemail\\\myphonenumber}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% sections
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}
  {}% no number
  {0pt}% no space
  {}% title
  [\titlerule]
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*2}{*1}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*1}{0pt}

% itemize
\setlist[itemize,1]{nosep,leftmargin=*}


% personal commands
\newcommand{\sbullet}{%
  \texorpdfstring{\textsbullet}{\textbullet}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textsbullet}{%
  \unskip~\,\begin{picture}(1,1)(0,-3)\circle*{3}\end{picture}\ %
}

\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{\section{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvsubsection}[3]{%
  \subsection{\textbf{#1} #2\texorpdfstring{\hfill}{ }#3}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}

% metadata
\input{constants}
\date{08/22/11}

\begin{document}

\section{Relevant Domain Knowledge \& Experience}

\cvsubsection{Conference \& Meetup Talks}{}{}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Learning Python with Best Practices \sbullet Python Best Practices \sbullet Functional Programming with Python
  \item Python by Aaron Hall - a nuts and bolts overview of Python to programmers of other languages
  \item Conference talks - Linear Models with Python \sbullet The Python Datamodel: When and how to write objects 
        \sbullet Best Practices for Writing Reusable Python
  \item Consulted on Python Data Science Curriculum and instructed Python classes at CUNY and Columbia
  \item Organized and Tutored Python Office Hours Sundays for a solid year from 2014 to 2015 - still organize.
\end{itemize}

\cvsubsection{Programming Languages}{}{}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Primary experience: Python, JSON, OODB, YAML, BASH, HTML, RST, Orgmode, \& other Markdowns
  \item Some experience with R, SAS, SPSS, Stata, and modified Prolog
  \item Toyed with: C, Ruby, Rails, Haskell, Lisp, Fortran, COBOL, Javascript, \& \LaTeX  
\end{itemize}

\cvsubsection{Investment, Financial Products, and Accounting Knowledge}{}{}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Securities Licensed on Packaged Products, Stocks \& Bonds, Options, and Investment Advisor Regulations
  \item Passed State of Florida Insurance and Real Estate Licensure Courses and Tests
  \item Answered over 150 Accounting and Tax Questions on Investments Pro-bono for All-Experts.com
\end{itemize}

\cvsection{Professional Experience}
\cvsubsection{\anonemployer}
  {\emph{Software Engineer \& Architect} \sbullet New York City, NY}{}
%  {October 2012 - Present}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Developed Portal for Delivering Documentation, Information, Statistics, and Reports
  \item Led Team to use Core Technology, Idiomatic Python, Maintainable Style, Proper Unittesting, and Proper SDLC
  \item Wrote Documentation and Training on Access Control, Proprietary OODB, Python, IDE, Sphinx, and Batch Jobs
  \item Developed Tool to Document Filesets, Provide Actionable Statistics, Push to Environments, and Raise Review Requests
  \item Reviewed Projects for Best Practices \& Edited Scripts for Performance, Maintainability, and Readability
  \item Instructed Developers in Best Practices with Weekly Webinars and Regular Code Review
  \item Developed GUI for 2nd generation Release Management Tool with Pretty Urls
  \item Developed Extension to Python Logging API
  \item Developed Library to Export Data from native Python to Tableau
\end{itemize}

\cvsubsection{Simplify IT}
 {\emph{Computer Technician} \sbullet New York, NY}
 {March, 2012 - May, 2012}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Troubleshot Computers and Networks, Audited and Installed Software
  \item Uploaded and Managed Inventory in an Amazon Web Store, Working With CSV and Flat Files
\end{itemize}

\cvsubsection{Thornhill Community Supportive Services Inc.}
 {\emph{Assistant Director} \sbullet New York, NY}
 {August, 2011 - February, 2012}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Operation Planning, Risk Management, and Network, Computer, Accounting, and Electronic Document Administration
  \item Led Team of 17 in Providing Computer Literacy and Coat, Toy, Book, and Media Community Distribution Programs
\end{itemize}

\cvsubsection{Pvt. Invest. Advisor/Sol Strategies}
  {\emph{Investment/Strategic Planning} \sbullet New York, NY}
  {April, 2007 - October, 2012}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Advised Sol Strategies on Firm Strategy, Business Development, Cash-Flow Management, and Billing Policy
  \item Consulted on Strategy and Wrote Financial, Investment, and Business Plans and Grant Applications
\end{itemize}

\cvsubsection{Florida State University}
  {\emph{Research Assistant} \sbullet Tallahassee, FL}
  {August, 2007 - April, 2008}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Teaching Fellow, Graded for Mergers and Acquisitions, Assisted in Data Collection, Research, and Proctoring Exams
  \item Programmed in SAS, Stata, SPSS, and R and Performed Regressions on Econometric Data
\end{itemize}

\cvsubsection{Merrill Lynch}
  {\emph{Financial Advisor} \sbullet Pensacola, FL}
  {May, 2006 - April, 2007}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Hosted Speakers, Brought in \$3 Million in Accounts, and Serviced More Than 100 House Accounts
  \item Executed Trades and Limit Orders on Exchange Traded Funds, Stocks, Options, and Auction Rate Securities
\end{itemize}

\cvsubsection{Ameriprise Financial Services}
  {\emph{Financial Advisor} \sbullet New York, NY}
  {January, 2004 - August, 2005}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Gave Seminars, Sold Financial Plans, Met Sales Goals, and Applied Monte Carlo Simulation \& Modern Portfolio Theory
  \item Series 7 Securities, Series 66 Investment Advisor, Life Insurance, Health Insurance, and Variable Annuity Licensed
\end{itemize}

\cvsection{Education}
\cvsubsection{University Of West Florida}
  {\emph{Master of Business Administration} \sbullet College of Business \sbullet Pensacola, FL}
  {August 2010}

\begin{itemize}
  \item 730 GMAT, 3.6 GPA, 486 Item Bibliographic Database, and International Business Strategy Championship winner
  \item Notable Papers: Predictors of Stock Market Values (Time Series) and Marketing Financial Services (Best in Class)
  \item Statistics Courses: Econometrics \sbullet Applied Regression \sbullet Probability and Statistics \sbullet Special Topics \sbullet Quantitative Methods
  \item Finance: Financial Management \sbullet Accounting Aspects \sbullet Advanced Managerial Economics \sbullet Static Optimization
\end{itemize}

\cvsubsection{Florida State University}
  {\emph{Bachelor of Science, Political Science \& Real Estate} \sbullet Tallahassee, FL}
  {April 2002}

\begin{itemize}
  \item National Merit Scholar, Dean’s List, and Graduated with 169 credit hours, 3.4 GPA, Served on Boards, Volunteered
  \item Real Estate Courses: Real Estate \sbullet Real Estate Finance \sbullet Appraisal I \& II \sbullet Feasibility \sbullet Legal Environment 
  \item Relevant: Game Theory \sbullet Financial Accounting \sbullet Managerial Accounting \sbullet Corporate Finance \sbullet Calculus \sbullet International Relations \sbullet Macroeconomics \sbullet Microeconomics \sbullet Comparative Government \sbullet Quantitative Methods \sbullet Research Methods
\end{itemize}

\cvsection{Interests, \& Miscellany}

Big Data, Databases (Hadoop, MongoDB, etc), Attended Strata 2011, Statistics, Finance, Economics, Machine Learning\\
Extensive Bibliographies: User Experience, Software Design, Finance Classics, Knowledge, and Management

\end{document}
```

As usual, the `filecontents` environment is only used for making the code self-contained.

[image]

Comment: Seems like when I first started tweaking on a LaTeX resume, it had lots of comment characters at each endline, and without them, the whitespace (blank lines) seems significant. What specifically should I do about that?

Comment: @AaronHall Blank line means end of paragraph

Comment: "Better using the “new syntax” for fancyhdr" - does this mean the Headers and footers section? Do you have an opinion on the header being on both pages? How might one remove it from the second page? Can the pagebreaking be prevented over each section?